# How do I get the user's email address from Google Contacts API without making a second request?

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, google-contacts-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to get a user's group contacts.  Normally I can use 'default' which is the user's email address but this does not work in the query parameter for the group ID.  I have a workaround by making two requests to the API, the first to gather the user's email address and the second to use it in the group request.  How can I get the user's email to only make a single request?

functional workaround:

```
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    resp, content = http.request('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json', method="GET")
    feed = json.loads(content)
    user_email = feed['feed']['id']['$t']
    resp, content = http.request('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&group=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/%s/base/6&max-results=100' % user_email, method="GET")
```

Comment: Even I couldn't think different solution other than getting useremail from https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full and sending this useremail parameter into http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/{userEmail}/base/{groupId}

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference